# Yii2 (php): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect from Yii2 app to db. It leads to error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

But I can connect to db with Workbench or from console with the same credentials.

I am using XAMP on macOS Mojave.
Yii2 config: 
    /xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/cms/config/cms_dev.php

```
return [
  'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cms_dev;port=3306',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '12345678',
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
];
```

First attempt was with 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1' but there was another error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Workbench:
   [image]

So I believe something in Yii2 should be changed.
[image: stack trace]
[image: xampp services]

Output of - 'netstat -an | grep 3306':

```
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.3306         127.0.0.1.50212        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.50212        127.0.0.1.3306         ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.3306         127.0.0.1.50211        ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.50211        127.0.0.1.3306         ESTABLISHED
tcp46      0      0  *.33060                *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.3306                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Under which folder you are changing connection string?

Comment: Try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: try `'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms_dev',` instead of  `'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cms_dev;port=3306',`

Comment: @WebArtisan updated with info about folder

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam updated

Comment: is your application running inside a docker container ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam no, without docker

Comment: can you show the full stack trace

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam added part of stack trace. I run XAMPP but I am trying to connect to mysql installed on laptop not to that which goes with XAMPP. Just as assumption, is it possible that XAMPP looking for own mysql which is inactive?

Comment: PHP is going to attempt to connect to an IP address and PORT as specified. It won't care if it is XAMPP or not. When you see connection refused, it means that the application cannot connect to the service. And this usually means the service isn't running. Try `netstat -an | grep 3306` to see if MySQL is listening.

Comment: @ryantxr updated with netstat output